# Spring Boot Security -Basic Authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Im using spring boot secuirty to implement the basic authetication . Below is my code .My role-based authorization is bypassed and basic authentication is not working .Without credentials also my service is giving response not throwing any error .It is not throwing any error when I pass wrong credentials .How to fix this error .Can anyone suggest ?

```
package com.agcs.cids.security;


@Configuration

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // Authentication : User --> Roles
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("Secret1").roles("USER");

    }

 
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/id").hasAuthority("USER");
            

    }

}
```

My Controller Class has mutiple endpoints :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/claims", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class Controller {

    

    /**
     * @param policyIdentifier
     * @param lineOfBusiness
     * @param broker
     
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object getClaimsBySearchCriteria(@RequestParam(value = "id") String userId ) throws ParseException, JsonProcessingException, javax.xml.bind.ValidationException {
                                          
        Query query = new Query();
       // int queryLimit = 1000;
       
        if (policyIdentifier != null && !policyIdentifier.isEmpty())
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("Common.PolicyId").is(policyIdentifier));
        
        List<Claims> claims = mongoOps.find(query, Claims.class);
        LOG.info("Claims returned: " + claims.toString());
        return claims;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getClaimsService() {
        LOG.info("Claims service is available");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/id/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getClaims(@RequestParam(value = "userId") String userId,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "id") String id) throws JsonProcessingException {
        MongoDatabase database = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(this.database);
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(this.collection);
        Document query = new Document("_id", new ObjectId(id));
        FindIterable<Document> documentCursor = collection.find(query);
        List<Document> claimsUpdatedList = null;
       
        for (Document doc : documentCursor) {
            claimsUpdatedList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (null != doc.get("Common")) {
                Document common = (Document) doc.get("Common");
                if (null != common.get("EffectiveDate")) {
                    Date date = (Date) common.get("EffectiveDate");
                    common.put("EffectiveDate",convertDate(date));
                }
                if (null != common.get("ExpirationDate")) {
                    Date date = (Date) common.get("ExpirationDate");
                    common.put("ExpirationDate",convertDate(date));
                }
                doc.put("Common",common);
                claimsUpdatedList.add(doc);
            }
        }
        JsonWriterSettings writerSettings = JsonWriterSettings.builder().outputMode(JsonMode.SHELL).indent(true).build();
        return claimsUpdatedList != null ? claimsUpdatedList.get(0).toJson(writerSettings) : null;
    }


    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("{noop}Secret1").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/claims/id/").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

- path is `/claims/id/`, not `/id/`
- you defined `USER` as role name, not as authority name, so required `hasRole()`
- call `httpBasic()` to to basic-auth ([10.10.2. Basic Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-basic))
- add a prefix `{noop}` to password ([Password Storage Format](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage-dpe-format))

[example code](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/en62574231)

Comment: Thank for your suggestion .It is working properly but  without password it is giving proper response instead of throwing an Error .And also with wrong password it is giving valid response ,Usually it has to throw exception with wrong password .Can you please suggest how to fix this error.

Comment: `curl -D - -u 'foo:bar' 'http://localhost:8080/claims/id/?userId=xxx&id=yyy'
` will return `401(Unauthorized)`, is normal hehavior. Can you be more specific about your expected response?

Comment: I am implemementing basic authentication with spring boot and added all above syntax .It is working properly but the problem is only with the password . It is accepting any password and not throwing any proper Error.How do fix this issue. Below is the syntax of code .public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("{noop}Secret1").roles("USER");
    }

Comment: What is your requesting url?(Is `http://localhost:8080/claims/id/?userId=xxx&id=yyy` expected url? )

Comment: Yes , My requesting URL is http://localhost:808/0claims/id/?userId=xxx&id=xxxx

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

Use `.antMatchers("/id/**").hasRole("USER");` instead of `.antMatchers("/id").hasAuthority("USER");`

Comment: I tried with the above solution , but its not working .I am testing in Postman and deleted the cookies also . Without authentication also it is giving the response and it is not taking configured credentials .It is not taking  User :user1 and password :Secret1 . It is not throwing the error with the wrong credentials.

Comment: Try omitting the `{noop}` and just set the password to `.password("Secret1")`

Comment: I have removed {noop} and set the password as suggested ,but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/id/**").hasAnyRole("USER").and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
```

Comment: I tried with the above solution , but its not working .I am testing in Postman and deleted the cookies also . Without authentication also it is giving the response and it is not taking configured credentials .It is not taking  User :user1 and password :Secret1 . It is not throwing the error with the wrong credentials.